# Trying to read the status of a user in my mysql databse from php

Tags: php, mysql, database, fatal-error, url-parsing

Trying to read the status of a user in my mysql database from php

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Find status for row with Username of the Url?username=
$sql = "SELECT Status FROM Users WHERE Username = '".$_GET["username"]."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die('Error connecting to database');
$username = mysql_result($result, 0, "Status");

echo 'Username Status is ' . $Status;
mysqli_close($conn);


?>
```

In result I'm getting is this:

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_query() in /storage/ssd4/269/2113269/public_html/teststat.php:11 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /storage/ssd4/269/2113269/public_html/teststat.php on line 11`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax for **mysqli** is not correct, because **mysqli** is different from **mysql** syntax.

> MySQLi stands for MySQL improved. It's an object-oriented interface to
>   the MySQL bindings which makes things easier to use.

I suggest you to use the **mysqli** version and don't mixup **mysql** syntax with **mysqli** syntax.

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT Status FROM Users WHERE Username = '".$_GET["username"]."'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row or remove while loop if you wish
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo 'Username Status is ' . $row['Status'] ;
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

Comment: Perfect thank you! It's because in trying to make this script work better I copied from an old website (it used mysql).

Answer (score 0):

You mixed up mysql and mysqli

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die('Error connecting to database');
$username = mysql_result($result, 0, "Status");
```